# Framer motion layout doesn't initially work

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to animate layout between hover on two buttons, with smooth transition. First mouse move on those elements doesn't animate, however if i keep moving mouse between those elements, they will animate later.

```
      <LayoutGroup id="background">
        <Btn key="Games" hovered={hovered} setHovered={setHovered} name="Games" />
        <Btn
          hovered={hovered}
          setHovered={setHovered}
          name="Community"
        />
      </LayoutGroup>
```

and Btn:

```
function Btn({ hovered, setHovered, name }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      key={name}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(name)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(undefined)}
      className="h-full w-40 relative bg-transparent"
    >
      {hovered === name ? (
        <motion.div
          layoutDependency={hovered}
          layoutId="background"
          className="w-full h-full absolute bg-orange-400"
        />
      ) : null}
      {name}
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```